# Multiple Error-Handlers in rabbitmq Publish function while using Promise based api

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using the rabbitmq publish function and the multiple error handlers caught my attention. The inner one is arrow function just below publish fn and is passed as argument in the publish function, the outer one the catch block .Is it the inner error handler was part of original callback based api and not needed now when we are using the promise based api? Need your expert opinion here

```
try 
{
    let channel = await this.init(this);//seperate fn that returns channel
    await channel.publish(exchange, routingKey, Buffer.from(message),  
        (err) => { 
            if(err) logger.error(`rabbitmq :: publish, ERROR IN PUBLISHING OPERATION: ${err}`); 
        }
    );

} catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error(`rabbitmq :: publish, ERRORS WHILE PUBLISHING MESSAGE, ERROR: ${err}`));
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean, not sure I fully understand. By inner handler do you mean Promise.reject inside the catch block? I think that's just a way to re-write/customize the error prefixing the relevant info ("rabbitmq :: publish,...")

Comment: @laggingreflex Thanks, I have updated my question and hope its clear now. inner handler is the arrow function and outer is the catch block.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like it's mixing both APIs - Callback and Promise.